# StackedXYAreaChart - why does the series value get added?

Tags: java, jfreechart

[image]

I am plotting a stackedXYAreaChart. For the same time period, if I plot values for two different series, the second values is added to the first. Is that supposed to happen ?
Why is that value for series 2 - 105 is actually extended to 185?

Here's my code:

```
package test;   

import java.awt.BorderLayout;   
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;   
import org.jfree.chart.*;   
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator;   
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CrosshairState;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;   
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;   
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StackedXYAreaRenderer2;   
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRendererState;
import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimePeriod;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeTableXYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.*;   

public class Test2   
{   

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   

    public Test2(String s)   
    {     
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());  
        JPanel jpanel = new ChartPanel(jfreechart);   
        JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        masterPanel.add(jpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        masterPanel.add(addUserControls(jfreechart), BorderLayout.EAST);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(masterPanel);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }   

    private static TimeTableXYDataset createDataset()   
    {   
        TimeTableXYDataset xyseries = new TimeTableXYDataset();

        xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 5D, "Series 1");   
        xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 10D, "Series 1");   
        xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 15D, "Series 1");   
        xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 20D, "Series 1");   

        xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 15D, "Series 2");   
        xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 20D, "Series 2");   
        xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 25D, "Series 2");   
        xyseries.add(new Millisecond(), 30D, "Series 2");   

        TimePeriod period = new Millisecond();
        xyseries.add(period, 59, "Series 1");
        xyseries.add(period, 70, "Series 2");
        period = new Millisecond();
        xyseries.add(period, 85, "Series 1");
        xyseries.add(period, 105, "Series 2");

        return xyseries;   
    }   

    private static JFreeChart createChart(TableXYDataset tablexydataset)   
    {   
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart("Stacked XY Area Chart Demo 1", "X Value", "Y Value", tablexydataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);   
        XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot)jfreechart.getPlot();   
        StackedXYAreaRenderer2 stackedxyarearenderer2 = new StackedXYAreaRenderer2() {
            public void drawItem(Graphics2D g2,
                     XYItemRendererState state,
                     Rectangle2D dataArea,
                     PlotRenderingInfo info,
                     XYPlot plot,
                     ValueAxis domainAxis,
                     ValueAxis rangeAxis,
                     XYDataset dataset,
                     int series,
                     int item,
                     CrosshairState crosshairState,
                     int pass) {
    if (!getItemVisible(series, item)) {
        return;
    }
    super.drawItem(g2, state, dataArea, info, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, series, item, crosshairState, pass);
    }
        };   
        stackedxyarearenderer2.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());   
        xyplot.setRenderer(0, stackedxyarearenderer2);   
        return jfreechart;   
    }   

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel()   
    {   
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());   
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);   
    }   

    public static void main(String args[])   
    {   
        Test2 stackedxyareachartdemo1 = new Test2("Stacked XY Area Chart Demo 1");   
    }   

    public JPanel addUserControls(JFreeChart chartPlot) {
        JPanel userPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        JCheckBox Series0Button = new JCheckBox("Series 1");
        Series0Button.setSelected(true);
        Series0Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Series count" + chartPlot.getXYPlot().getSeriesCount());
                if (Series0Button.isSelected()) {
                StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
                renderer.setSeriesVisible(0, Boolean.TRUE, true);
                } else {
                    StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
                    renderer.setSeriesVisible(0, Boolean.FALSE, true);
                }
            }
        });

        JCheckBox series1Button = new JCheckBox("Series 2");
        series1Button.setSelected(true);
        series1Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (series1Button.isSelected()) {
                StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
                renderer.setSeriesVisible(1, Boolean.TRUE, true);
                } else {
                    StackedXYAreaRenderer2 renderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) chartPlot.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
                    renderer.setSeriesVisible(1, Boolean.FALSE, true);
                }
            }
        });
        userPanel.add(Series0Button);
        userPanel.add(series1Button);
        return userPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a simple `XYAreaChart` if you don't want the "stacking" effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that the value for series `2`—`105` is actually extended to `185`?

This "stacking" is the expected behavior of [`StackedXYAreaRenderer2`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/StackedXYAreaRenderer2.html). The actual range value is `190`, which equals `85 + 105`.

```
xyseries.add(period, 85, "Series 1");
xyseries.add(period, 105, "Series 2");
```

The effect may be easier to see if you zoom in or add more data.

Also, note that Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: You mean the stacked area chart is supposed to add the values whatsoever ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes; same for `StackedXYAreaRenderer`.